# Unable to remove element of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Try so many ways of removing an element from array element

I have declare an array vehicleObj as such

```
var vehicleObj = [{
    regNo: "XX09WP", 
    model: "Ford KA", 
    repaircost: "23.89",
    typeRepair: "exhust"
}];
```

And here is my loop

```
vehicleObj.forEach(function(regNoPass,index){
   console.log(regNoPass);
   console.log("your in for each..");
   if(vehicleObj[index].regNo == regNoPass)
   {
      console.log("Magic has happen");
      vehicleObj.splice(regNoPass, 1);
   }
});
```

No matter what the regNoPass value is i.e. XX09WP it will not remove this from the array

Any ideas would be most welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change

```
vehicleObj.splice(regNoPass, 1);
```

to

```
vehicleObj.splice(index, 1);
```

because [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) needs the index, not the value (or there would be no need to loop over the array to find that index).

Note that if you don't need to keep the same array object, the whole could be expressed as

```
vehicleObj = vehicleObj.filter(function(v){
     return v.regNo !== regNoPass;
});
```